# Using "params" and "cookies" methods inside the a class under lib directory - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a class under lib folder to handle some geo-locations logic. This class is being initiated from controller method. I want this class to handle all the issues regarding geo locations which includes - querying a external api to find country from ip, set cookies if country found(so that external api's will not be called with user's each request). Say,

```
class GeoLocation
end
```

Now, inside this class, I want to access "params" method to access the parameters as well as "cookies" method to set the cookies and access them.

So what should I include in this class for these methods to work.
I tried with -

```
class GeoLocation
    include ActionController
    include ActionController::Cookies
end
```

But this gives errors.

I tried this as well -

```
class GeoLocation < ActionController::Base
```

But no use. So, how should i do this, or is there any better alternative to my approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `params` and `cookies` hashes are only available to your controllers and views. You cannot access them in a class.  You will have to define methods to manipulate the params / cookies hashes in the class, and pass them in from the controller.

```
class Geolocation
  def initialize params, cookies
    @parameters = params
    @cookies = cookies
  end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
def index
  geo = Geolocation.new(params, cookies)
  geo.parameters #parameter hash
  geo.cookies #cookies object
end
```

You'll probably want to read up on [instance variables in ruby](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).